# small part of navigation bar sticks off page

Tags: html, css

I have my width for the status bar set to 100% in CSS, but yet it is still a little bit more. The rest of my page all cuts off at the right spot but you can scroll right and see my status bar sticking off. Please help! All help is appreciated!

[Link to my site](http://www.aaronvigal.com)

CSS Code:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

div.navigation{
    width: 99%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: black;
}

a.navigation{
    color: #f5f5f5;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a.navigation:hover{
    color: grey;
}
a.navigation:active{
    color: darkred;
}
a.navigation:visited{
    color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: Could you clean up the CSS code to just the portion you need help with? I don't even know where to start looking without some HTML to guide, either.

Comment: Right after I posted that, you added a link. Answer is below.

Comment: you can try to put one tag inside another "container" tag like a div or something with width 100%, and style your content inside the container div the way you want

Comment: Please add the HTML to the question as well. This site is not just for you to get an answer to your specific question, but rather to help future readers as well. If/when your site changes or goes dark, this question will become less helpful to those readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS, you have some styles set on the navigation which are adding padding. Change the code starting at line 37 to:

```
div.navigation {
  width:100%;
  padding: 10px 0;  /* Keeps the padding to the top and bottom only */
  height:25px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Iff i take off the padding than it messes up the rest of the navigation bar. :/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but that also didn't work :\ I can't get it for the life of me!

Comment: Okay, If you take a look now, it fixed but now the height is thrown off! i had to change it to "padding:10 10;"

Comment: I think you mean `padding: 10px 0;`.  What you have suggested would set the top and bottom to 0px but keep the left and right at 10px.  @AaronVigal.  `padding:10 10` is effectively `padding:0 0`.  If specifying a value greater or less than 0, you have to specify a unit - E.g. `px`, otherwise the browser will interpret the value as 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your padding is causing the browser to interpret the width of the bar as 100% of it's container width **plus 20px of padding** (10px left and 10px right).

You can use the CSS `box-sizing: border-box;` property to force the browser to render the box with the specified width and height, and place the border and padding inside the box.

```
div.navigation{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Note you will need to increase the height to 45px because the browser will not extend the height of the box for the top and bottom padding.

JS Fiddle [fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/pry5tmmp/2/embedded/result/); [code](http://jsfiddle.net/pry5tmmp/2/).

Comment: or fix the padding with the width calculation (padding:10px 2%; width:96%)

Comment: yes -  adjusting he padding to a % value will also wrk, although to cover only 100%, it should be width:98%;padding:10px 1% (1% left + 1% right).

Comment: Ooop's, my bad - didn't see you had added the width. Viewing on the iPhone app! You are of course, correct!